# How to debug properly in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I'm using debugger in my code in multiple apps. However, I usually have to debug because of loops where one specific thing went wrong. Is there a way to let the debugger fast forward or autopilot to the point where I hit an error? I'm sick of using 'next' over and over until I get to the correct point in the loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the debugger statement with a conditional.  Something like this:

```
my_collection.each do |l|

  debugger if l.has_some_bad_condition?

  # ...
end
```